# Improving a Javascript browser detection function

Tags: javascript

I’ve written a Javascript browser detection function but I’d like to improve it with everyone else’s knowledge.

Problems:

You’ll notice that I’m assuming that a “Chrome 18” must be a “Maxthon 3” but of course that is not necessarily so!

How can we differentiate between Chrome 18 and Maxthon 3?

Similarly, how can we differentiate between Firefox and Sea Monkey?

And what about Lunar? Can we also detect that browser via navigator.userAgent?

Is there any other popular browser I’ve forgotten about?

Only pure Javascript solutions/suggestions please!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function GetBrowser(){
 var browser="";
 var version=0;

 if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
  browser="FireFox";} else {

  if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
   browser="Internet Explorer";} else {

   if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
    browser="Opera";} else {

    if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
     if (version==18) {version=3; browser="Maxthon";} else {browser="Google Chrome"}} else {version=0; browser="Undetermined";}
 }}}
 return browser+' '+version;}

 document.write(GetBrowser());
 </script>
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Do you realize that browser detection from the user agent is a horrible way of doing things? And this has been done many time on the net, a simple google search shows that.

Comment: Why are you trying to detect browsers? in *most* cases feature detection is much better.

Comment: If you *must* use browser detection (of which there are very few - but admittedly some - "good" cases), please an existing *well maintained* library ..

Comment: So the answers so far are... why bother? and Do you have to? :)

Comment: @pst Btw, if everyone relied on every else's work there wouldn't be any libraries for you to use!

Comment: The problem @mariospolycarpou is that browser detection is fragile (browsers (or the users) can/do masquerade as other browsers), and parsing the user agent string is very tricky due to random crud that some vendors include. Even when it works, as a developer you start depending on "oh, this is IE, therefore it doesn't support X" which may be true at one point, but then changes over time.

Comment: Ok let’s all just give up and go to bed because everything is bad!

Comment: Lets just start over... What is the problem you are trying to solve by having a JavaScript browser detection function?... because whatever that issue is, we can likely provide you with a simple solution.

Comment: Don’t worry about it mate! I’m in the wrong place… catch you people later.

Comment: I recommend using a library.

Comment: @mariospolycarpou You already rely on work other people have done when you use Javascript or any other programming language (or web browser, operating system, etc.) so disregarding software development that builds off the work of others is pure foolishness.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is what I neded up with. I Corrected bugs in Opera and Safari version detections and added SeaMonkey.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function GetBrowser(){
 var browser="";
 var version=0;

 if (/SeaMonkey[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
  browser="SeaMonkey";} else {

  if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
   browser="Mozilla FireFox";} else {

   if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
    browser="Internet Explorer";} else {

    if (/Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     if (/Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){version=new Number(RegExp.$1);}
     browser="Opera";} else {

     if (/Maxthon[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
      version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
      browser="Maxthon";} else {

      if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
       version=new Number(RegExp.$1);
       browser="Google Chrome";} else {

       if (/Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        if (/Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){version=new Number(RegExp.$1);}
        browser="Safari";} else {browser="Unknown";}

 }}}}}}
 return browser+' '+version;}


 document.write(GetBrowser());

 </script>
```

Comment: The first thing I'd recommend is learning how to format if/else braces properly.  You're asking to introduce bugs the way you're doing it.  The next suggestion is to forget about re-inventing the wheel: use an existing library.  Nobody is going to give you pointers on your code because your entire approach is wrong.

Comment: There’s no international standard in code formatting for ANY programming language so it’s pointless to complain about anyone’s style just because it doesn’t suit your eyes.

What you can do is write a “pretty printer” in your favorite 3GL (like we did in the old days) and format other people’s code in whichever style you like. It’s an interesting string parsing challenge if you’re up to it.

As for getting any help with this… I did it and it works flawlessly so thanks for all the fish!

Ta ta!

Comment: Actually, every language DOES have style guidelines. Have you been living in a cave? There's no law that you have to follow them, but most sensible people do.  Good luck with your programming.

Comment: Then please don't assume that I'm "sensible"... :)

Answer (score 2):

A nice browser/feature detection is implemented in Modernizr http://modernizr.com/ which also supported by some CDNs like CDNjs http://cdnjs.com/

What I want to figure out is that you can detect some browser supported features and so you can simply detect a browser by a small difference.

Comment: With all due respect but suggesting 3rd party libraries should not be permissible in a programming forum, unless of course you want to rename it to something like… 

“The programmer’s library exchange!” or “Johnny learns jigsaw puzzles!”

Comment: @mariospolycarpou - You couldn't be more wrong.  Why on earth would you opt against using a library?  Some tasks (such as the one you've chosen) are complicated enough that it makes _zero_ sense to ignore existing libraries that can do the job for you.  Do you plan to implement your own web server as well??

Comment: Just go buy ready made software and don't worry about coding! :)