# How can I detect which browser is used with feature detection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, browser-detection

I wish to detect various browsers with feature detection in JavaScript from IE7-11, Chrome and Firefox. How can I do this>

Comment: Then it's no longer feature detection, but browser detection, the thing one tries to avoid by using feature detection ?

Comment: The whole point of feature detection is to not do that.

Comment: you can look for "smoking guns" associated with each browser you're looking for. not every single version of all browsers has one of those, but each version of IE will for sure. work your way backwards on caniuse to find globals supported by certain IE version, ex btoa, XMLHttpRequest, FileReader(), etc.

Comment: Ok, I clearly got it all mixed up. Can someone point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: The way that feature detection should be used is that when you need to do something, you check if that feature is available, and then use it. If it's not, then you (hopefully) fall back to some alternative method. If that alternative method isn't universally supported, then you'd need to check if whatever feature it uses is supported, and then use it. if not, then fall back again. Rinse and repeat as necessary. Doing it like this, you never need to care about which browser is being used, only which features are supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improving a Javascript browser detection function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316353/improving-a-javascript-browser-detection-function)

Comment: http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser#answer-9851769

Answer (score 0):

As @dandavis said, look objects specific to the browser you need. For example:

```
if (!document.characterSet || !document.doctype || !document.defaultView) {
        /**
         * If the browser does not have these properties on the document,
         * then it is probably IE8 or lower... Maybe.
         */
}
```